# How do you use foldl to find out the number of times a letter is repeated in a string?

Tags: string, testing, erlang, anonymous-function, fold

I'm new to Erlang and am testing different functions around to get a grasp of them. I want this function to be able to return an integer that says the number of times a letter variable is repeated in a string using the foldl function but am kinda stuck with deciding the "fun" function. Any help?

Examples of what I want the function to return:

```
`test:count("Hello this is a test", $i)`
```

should return 2

```
test:count("Hello this is a test", $t)
```

should return 3

```
-spec count(String, Char) -> integer() when
  String::string(),
  Char::char().

count(String, Char) ->

F = ???,

lists:foldl(F, 0, String).
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. Have you tried any value for `F` yet?

Answer (score 1):

Following on the Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil's answer, you could also write fold like this:

```
count(String, Char) ->
  F = fun(C, Count) when C=:=Char-> Count + 1;
         (_, Count)              -> Count
      end,
  lists:foldl(F, 0, String).
```

Comment: $ erlc count.erl
count.erl:5: Warning: variable 'Char' is unused
count.erl:6: Warning: variable 'Char' is unused
count.erl:6: Warning: variable 'Char' shadowed in 'fun'
count.erl:7: Warning: this clause cannot match because a previous clause at line 6 always matches

Comment: BTW, it is one of reasons I hesitate use lists:fold/3. I would be first who would like to write it in this way because I love pattern matching but you can't. Function clause head always introduces fresh new variables and same apply for funs. No fun there :-(

Comment: Well, now it works but not a big win over `if`, isn't it? You could even check if compiler produces different bytecode. There would be the only difference in an exception if your second fun clause would not be catch-all.

Comment: You are right Hynek, I Should have compiled first. Corrected the code.

Comment: Difference in bytecode is only numbers of line: `$ diff count.S.{1,2}
21c21
<     {line,[{location,"count.erl",9}]}.
---
>     {line,[{location,"count.erl",11}]}.
52c52
<     {line,[{location,"count.erl",6}]}.
---
>     {line,[{location,"count.erl",7}]}.`

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil, Thanks for your comments, I've learnt couple of lessons today. Could you tell me how do you get to the byte code?

Comment: `erlc +S count.erl` or `c(count, ['S']).` in `erl` shell. See documenation of [`compile`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html) application for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
F = fun(C, Acc) ->
    %% Fill this in yourself ;)
end,
```

Keep in mind that the value you return in your function `F` is the value of the accumulator `Acc` on the next iteration. In the last iteration, the current value of the accumulator `Acc` will then be returned by `lists:foldl/3`.

On your code, the first iteration's `Acc` value will be `0`, as you put in the second parameter of `lists:foldl/3`. You're in the right track.

Your function simply needs to compare if the current character `C` is equivalent to `Char`. If it is, increment `Acc` and return it. Otherwise, don't increment `Acc` and return the same variable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried  
F = fun(C, Acc) -> if  

                          C == Char ->   

                            Acc + 1;  

                          C /= Char -> Char  

                       end,  

    
    lists:foldl(F, 0, String).   


But get strange errors. As you mentioned I compared the variable with the Char  and added one to the accumulator, otherwise I returned the Char. But  for some reason I get a syntax error for the "." and a complaint about function "count/2 being undefined"....

Comment: You can change `C /= Char ` and use `true` instead since you want it to act as an `else` condition. And my bad, on the same variable, I meant to say the `Acc` variable not `C` nor `Char`.

Comment: @A.Sh You have missing `end` for your `if`. You also should return `Acc` instead of `Char` and last minor remark you should use `=:=` and `=/=` instead of `==` and `/=` unless you deal with `<` and `>` comparisons. So you should write something like `F = fun(C, Acc) -> if C =:= Char -> Acc + 1; true -> Acc end end, lists:foldl(F, 0, String).`

Comment: @A.Sh Anyway why you use `lists:foldl/3` when directly written tail recursive function will be shorter and more efficient `count(String, Char) -> c(Char, String, 0). c(_, [], A) -> C; c(C, [C|T], A) -> c(C, T, A+1); c(C, [_|T], A) -> c(C, T, A).` I found it more readable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Length of occurrences of a particular character in a string will do the same.

```
count(String, Char) ->                                                                                                                                                               
    Occurrences = [ X || X <- String, X == Char],                                                                                                                                            
    length(Occurrences).
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not use `lists:foldl/3` at all.

```
count(String, Char) ->
    count(Char, String, 0).

count(_, [], Count) -> Count;
count(C, [H|T], Count) ->
    count(C, T, if C =:= H -> Count+1; true -> Count end).
```

or more often simply

```
count(_, [],    Count) -> Count;
count(C, [C|T], Count) -> count(C, T, Count+1);
count(C, [_|T], Count) -> count(C, T, Count).
```

but if you insist

```
count(String, Char) ->
    F = fun(C, Count) ->
            if C =:= Char -> Count + 1;
               true       -> Count
            end
         end,
    lists:foldl(F, 0, String).
```

Comment: Hynek, out of sheer curiosity, why wouldn't you not use foldl?

Comment: @AsierAzkuenaga: I don't see it as simpler or more readable. It is also less efficient and it was important in things I was used to doing. So I developed a habit of writing, reading and maintaining those simple recursions. I'm used to writing complex state machines directly in Erlang functions so this simple code seems obvious for me. I also believe explicit is better than implicit and `lists:fold/3` is somewhat implicit.